# How to assign a user a post with Mongoose and Express

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am currently stuck on how I could assign a user a post when they create when in the website. So basically I want to have a logged in user create a resume and then have that resume assigned to that logged in user as a created_by in the schema. I kind of got it sorted but I don't know to create the resume and assign the logged in user to it.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const ObjectId = Schema.ObjectId;
var moment = require('moment');
var id = require('../helpers/generator');
let beautifyUnique = require('mongoose-beautiful-unique-validation');


const ResumeSchema = new Schema({
  _id: {
    type: String,
    default: id.generate()
  },
  title: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  creator: {
    type: ObjectId,
    ref: "User"
  },
  description: {
    type: String,
    default: "No description provided."
  },
  company_reviews: {
    name: {
      type: String,
      default: "RSW"
    },
    review: {
      type: String,
      default: "asodsodo"
    },
    rating: {
      type: String,
      default: "10/10"
    }
  },
  employee_reviews: {
    name: {
      type: String,
      default: "Doge Dog"
    },
    company: {
      type: String,
      default: "RSW"
    },
    review: {
      type: String,
      default: "blah blah"
    },
    rating: {
      type: String,
      default: "10/10"
    }
  },
  createdAt: {
    type: String,
    default: moment(new Date()).format("MMM DD, YYYY") // "Sun, 3PM"
  }
});

var Resume = mongoose.model('Resume', ResumeSchema);
module.exports = Resume;
```

---

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var moment = require('moment');
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
var id = require('../../helpers/generator');
let beautifyUnique = require('mongoose-beautiful-unique-validation');


const UserSchema = new Schema({
    _id: {
        type: String,
        default: id.generate()
    },
    firstName: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    lastName: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    accountType: {
        type: String,
        enum: ['Alphaneer', 'Administrator', 'Support', 'PRO'],
        default: 'Alphaneer'
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true
    },
    username: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true,
        unique: true
    },
    bio: {
        type: String,
        default: "No bio provided."
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    createdAt: {
        type: String,
        default: moment(new Date()).format("MMM DD, YYYY") // "Sun, 3PM 17"
    }
});

// authenticate input against content from database. BLOODY HELL ITS A MESS
UserSchema.statics.authenticate = function(email, password, callback) {
    User.findOne({
            email: email
        })
        .exec(function(err, user) {
            if (err) {
                return callback(err);
            }
            bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, function(err, result) {
                if (result === true) {
                    return callback(null, user)
                } else {
                    return callback();
                }
            })
        })
}

UserSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
    var user = this;
    bcrypt.hash(user.password, 10, function(err, hash) {
        if (err) throw err;
        user.password = hash;
        console.log("LOG: Password hashed & user saved.");
        next();
    });
});

var User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);

module.exports = User;
```

---

And I want to create a Resume as the logged in user here

```
// POST /dashboard/resume/create
router.post('/resume/create', (req, res, next) => {
  Resume.create(req.body, (err, resume) => {
    if (err) {
      var err = new Error("Error:" + err);
      err.status = 404;
      next(err);
    } else {
      return res.redirect('/dashboard');
    }
  })
});
```

---

I also create a Resume when I register a user. Kind of a welcome thing

```
// POST /register
router.post('/', (req, res, next) => {
  var data = {
    firstName: req.body.fName,
    lastName: req.body.lName,
    username: req.body.username,
    email: req.body.email,
    password: req.body.password,
    bio: req.body.bio
  };
  User.create(data, (err, user) => {
    if (err) {
      throw err;
    }
    var resume = {
      title: "Welcome to NAME!"
    }
    Resume.create(resume, (err, resume) => {
      if (err) throw err;
      return res.redirect('/');
    });
  });
});
```

Any help is appreciated and I can also do some further explaining if it isn't making sense :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would that comes to my mind is to keep the referece of resume in user schema and whenever there is a `POST /resume/create, first save the resume object in the Resume schema and then update the user Schema with the resume reference. Since your user is logged in you should saved the logged in user details some where, say in req.user. Part of the code should go like this:

```
//add this code to your user Schema 
 resume: {
     type: Schema.objectId,
     ref: 'Resume'
 }
```

You should modify your register function to save the resume and update the resume reference in the user model.

```
// POST /dashboard/resume/create
router.post('/resume/create', (req, res, next) => {
  Resume.create(req.body, (err, resume) => {
    if (err) {
      var err = new Error("Error:" + err);
      err.status = 404;
      next(err);
    } else {
      //I am assuming that you have saved your resume and getting the saved object in `resume`, now update the logged in user in req.user
    var user = req.user;
    user.resume = resume._id;
 //save the updated user
    user.save((error, user) => {
      if(error) {
        //handle error
      } else {
       //you have saved the user with resume ref now.
        return res.redirect('/dashboard');
      }
    })
    }
  })
});
```

Comment: Okay, so req.user is the signed in user cause I use sessions? Would that be suitable here or should I stick with req.user?

Comment: I meant you should save the logged user resources somewhere. Sessions will do too, or if you want you can look into JWT (json web tokens) for token based authentication. Sign the token with user object and when the user makes an api request with the token, extract those details in req.user. One other method when you have the userId in the request url would be to use `req.params` and load the user object whenever userId is in params.

Comment: Okay, I am using JWT so perhaps I will do that. Thanks!